# Place geom_text below confidence intervals of a bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

How can I place `geom_text` below the confidence intervals(`geom_errorbar`) of a bar plot?

**The solutions I 've tried (but I did not liked):**

**1.** Change the colour and place it at the top of a bar char. This is good, but white on some colours is just wrong:

[image: White on yellow?!]

**2.** Put a high vjust, so it can go below the `confidence intervals`. Again, this is good, but not good enough. Not all `intervals` have the same height:

[image: Different interval sizes]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found a way to dynamically place the `geom_text` approximately below the `confidence intervals`. You might need to adjust the numbers: **1.5**, and **25**.

Basically it sums a number that is proportionate to the `confidence intervals`, and a constant value, that is that is approximately the same with the text's height.

```
   geom_text(data=statSummary, aes(label=sprintf("%.02f",time)),
        vjust=1.5 +
          ((statSummary$time -
          (statSummary$time-statSummary$ci))
        /
        (statSummary$time))*25
        ,
        position=position_dodge(width=0.9),
        show_guide=F,
        color="black")
```

If you use a ruler you might find the result not perfect, but it is much better:
[image]